# Three.js Curve.getPoint() to return a world coordinate

Tags: three.js, curve

I'm trying to get the position of a point on an ellipse curve on a world coordinate in Three.js, by using the following function:

```
pt = ellipse.getPoint(t[i]);
```

However, it returns a Vector2 object with the local coordinate defined with the ellipse.
Is there any method to transfer it to the global coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

This question is problematic because `EllipseCurve` is a 2D curve meaning it lies in a conceptual plane.

If you want to have sampled curve points in 3D space, you can of course copy the x and y coordinate to an instance of `Vector3` and then set the `z` component to e.g. `0`.

Also notice that unlike `THREE.Object3D`, the `THREE.Curve` class does not support hierarchical transformations. So the terms local and global scope do not make sense in this context. You would have to use your sampled points e.g. to create an instance of `THREE.Points` (a point cloud) so you can add it to the scene graph and transform it on object level.